# Codable MKPolygon?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mapkit, codable

Ok, bear with me.
I've got a database of coordinates, I'm trying to pull that data down, decode it into a codable class that also conforms to MKPolygon and then just be able to add that polygon to a map view.

```
class CustomPolygon : MKPolygon, Codable {

    var perimeter : [Coordinate]!

}
struct Coordinate : Codable {
    let Latitude : CLLocationDegrees
    let Longitude : CLLocationDegrees
    
    func getCoord() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.Latitude, longitude: self.Longitude)
    }
}
```

The important code when I am decoding it from the database is this:

```
let polygon = try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(CustomPolygon.self, from: data)
```

The encoding/decoding is with help from the CodableFirebase CocoaPod, and it successfully codes it, but now how do I add in the actual coordinates to create the polygon?

Comment: I don't think that subclassing `MKPolygon` is the right approach. I would create a `Codable` struct with a function or computed property that returns an instance of `MKPolygon` using the coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not advise subclassing `MKPolygon`. Frankly, I would not advise creating `CustomPolygon` and `Coordinate`, at all. There is no need to introduce types that mirror the native `MKPolygon` and `CLLocationCoordinate2D` types.

Rather than trying to make a codable `MKPolygon`, I might instead suggest creating a `Codable` type that just represents a collection of coordinates, which encodes an array of latitude and longitudes.

But first, let’s consider a JSON structure, an array of coordinates:

```json
[
    {"longitude":37.785834, "latitude":-122.406417},
    {"longitude":37.246878, "latitude":-122.245676},
    ...
]
```

So, I would create a type that encodes/decodes that as outlined in “Encode and Decode Manually” section of [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types):

```swift
struct Coordinates: Codable {
    var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

    // MARK: Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude, longitude
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let subcontainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            let latitude = try subcontainer.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self, forKey: .latitude)
            let longitude = try subcontainer.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self, forKey: .longitude)
            coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()

        for value in coordinates {
            var subcontainer = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            try subcontainer.encode(value.latitude, forKey: .latitude)
            try subcontainer.encode(value.longitude, forKey: .longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

I might also create some convenience methods to easily create `MKPolygon` and `MKPolyline` from a `Coordinates` and vice versa:

```swift
extension Coordinates {
    init(from polygon: MKPolygon) {
        self.polygon = polygon
    }

    init(from polyline: MKPolyline) {
        self.polyline = polyline
    }

    var polygon: MKPolygon {
        get { MKPolygon(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count) }
        set { updateCoordinates(from: newValue) }
    }

    var polyline: MKPolyline {
        get { MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count) }
        set { updateCoordinates(from: newValue) }
    }

    private mutating func updateCoordinates(from shape: MKMultiPoint) {
        let pointCount = shape.pointCount
        coordinates = .init(repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, count: pointCount)
        shape.getCoordinates(&coordinates, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pointCount))
    }
}

extension MKPolyline {
    var coordinates: Coordinates { Coordinates(from: self) }
}

extension MKPolygon {
    var coordinates: Coordinates { Coordinates(from: self) }
}
```

Then, if you want to encode the coordinates of a polygon:

```swift
let coordinates = polygon.coordinates            // if you need to extract the `Coordinates` collection from the `MKPolygon`
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(coordinates)
```

Or if you want to decode the coordinates and create a `MKPolygon` from them:

```swift
let coordinates = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coordinates.self, from: data)
let polygon = coordinates.polygon                // if you want to add a `MKPolygon` represented by this collection of `Coordinates`
```

But the idea is that your model objects would this `Coordinates` type (i.e. a collection of `CLLocationCoordinate2d`) that is `Codable`. Then you can use the `polygon` or `polyline` computed properties to build the appropriate `MKOverlay` type that you could then add to your map.

And because `Coordinates` is `Codable`, you now can use this type in your own `Codable` types, e.g.:

```swift
struct RegionOfInterest: Codable {
    let name: String
    let coordinates: Coordinates
}
```